# Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Version 1903 KB's which are must be installed

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-update

There are 2 KB's are hard-installed: **KB4497464** and **KB4497727**. So, I am assuming they're more important than other KB's. Hence the following link contains many of them; which of them has the same level of critical importance to have the "Must Install"?

[Windows 10 update history - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-history-e6058e7c-4116-38f1-b984-4fcacfba5e5d)

Comment: What does "hard installed" mean exactly?  Only one of those is a SSU which cannot be removed neither of them are recent nor even the current LCU. Considering 1903 is not supported, and an update hasn't been released in over 3 years, you will want to install the last update that was released.

Comment: It's just a guess. since I am unable to delete it.

Comment: Only one of those is a SSU which cannot be deleted, but both have already been replaced, by updates released in 2020. Check the Windows Update Catalog to determine which updates superseded those updates. All updates for an unsupported installation of Windows 10 1903 should be installed.  Furthermore 1903 shouldn't be installed, but I am sure there are reasons for using an unsupported version of Windows 10.

Comment: If the OS is 3 years out of date, it might be much quicker to download the latest ISO from MS and reinstall, rather than installing the many needed updates.